# I cant compare user input correctly with pre populated dictionary values

Tags: python

I am trying to make an arbitrary username and password program in python
i have a dictionary populated with a series of username and values
I am having trouble comparing user input with dictionary username and values.
they seem to not be equatable.

```
textFile = open('names.txt','r')
dictionary = {}
for lines in textFile:
    splatLine=lines.split('\t')
    dictionary[splatLine[3]]= splatLine[4]
print dictionary

userName= raw_input("what is your UserName:")
password= raw_input("what is your Password:")
```

Comment: Where in the code are you performing a comparison?

Comment: Your dictionary values still have line endings (\n) in them, your user input does not.  Strip the lines you read from names.txt before adding them to your dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your read the text in properly this will work.

```
dictionary = {"foo":"bar","Johnny":"Appleseed"}
uname = "foo"
pw = "nobar"
     for i in dictionary:
          if uname == i:
              if dictionary[i] == pw:
                   print "You're in"
              else:
                   print "all your base are belong to us"
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use *with* statement to close a opened file automatically, otherwise don't forget to close your file after read it. Also, *readline* method of file will return a line with the **trailing newline** character, you need to strip it off before compare with the user input.

```
with open('names.txt','r') as f:
    pwd_dict=dict([line.strip().split('\t')[3:5] for line in f])    
userName= raw_input("what is your UserName:")
password= raw_input("what is your UserName:")
if not (username in pwd_dict and password == pwd_dict[username]):
    ... ...
```